# WiFi плата. Соединение с сокетом на компьютере

Tags: linux, wifi, lan

У меня, так сказать, в комплекте есть:

> Плата, к которой присоединён модем с динамическим IP адресом и выходом в интернет.
>
> Программа Putty, при помощи которой я создаю соединение с платой (Плата соединена к компьютеру при помощи LAN кабеля).
>
> На компьютере запущен сервер на порту 5003. Доступен снаружи.

Вопрос: Как написать плате скрипт, который будет устанавливать соединение с моим сокетом, запущенным на компьютере, и, допустим, отправлять каждые 10 минут строчку "Hello World"?

Comment: Плата не выполняет никаких скриптов и с помощью putty вы соединяетесь не с платой, а с программой (скорее всего sshd), которая запущена на компьютере, которая в свою очередь скорее всего запускает командную оболочку, т.е. shell, т.е. какой нибудь /bin/sh в котором вы и работаете. А теперь определитесь для начала на каком из десятка предустановленных на linux языков программирования вы хотите написать скрипт. потом почитайте про этот язык и если будут неразрешимые вопропсы - обращайтесь

Comment: Я не знаю какой язык из десятка стоит у меня. Я только знаю, что эта плата - бывшый старый WiFi роутер :D))

Comment: Я знаю, что в этом языке используются неизвестные мне операторы "sudo", "nano", "cp", "copy"...

Comment: Это язык командной оболочки. и это не "операторы", а команды командной строки. Это примерно то же самое, что если вы под windows нажмете пуск->выполнить->cmd и в этом cmd будете давать команды dir, copy и т.п. И в самом языке shell "операторов" своих кот наплакал и вы ни одного не упомянули, все что вы назвали - это команды, которые на самом деле просто исполнимые программы, лежащие где нибудь в /bin, /usr/bin и некоторых других каталогах. В google наберите "unix shell" узнаете много интересного

Comment: Да, и в общем виде сам shell не может соединятся ни с какими портами других компов. (если опустить довольно замысловатые возможности bash, тем более что у вас shell может быть не bash). А с портом соединятся могут только другие программы. например `nc`. Такие вещи все таки не на shell принято писать, а на других языках.

Comment: Извините, но Вы новичек по программированию или по Linux или по программированию под Linux? Программировать Linux у Вас не получится. И, возможно, Вы не понимаете, что такое Linux. Так может для Вас станет это откровением, но это вполне себе полноценная операционная система, которая ничем не хуже той же Windows, из под которой Вы запустили Putty. И даже больше... Можно сказать, что Linux гораздо более распространен нежели Windows (с учетом распространнености ее ядра).

Comment: Но для начала... с каким языком программирования под Windows Вы знакомы? Какая программа (написанная Вами или нет) создает сокет под Windows, на который будет из под Linux отправляться "Hello World"?

Comment: @MaxZS, пожалуйста, не вводите людей в заблуждение. linux — это программа, выполняющая функции ядра в нескольких операционных системах.

Comment: @Lesperanza, для полноценного ответа требуется больше информации о возможностях операционной системы, установленной в вашем устройстве. хотя бы модель устройства назовите, возможно, это поможет идентифицировать операционную систему.

Comment: @MaxZS, читайте, пожалуйста, [мнение профессионалов](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/linux/info), а не дилетантов. я, как профессионал, своё мнение высказал. если вам угодно ознакомиться с моими аргументами подробнее, найдите дискуссии по этому поводу, в которых я участвовал несколько лет назад на unixforum.org.

Comment: @alexander barakin Хотелось бы вывести Вас из заблуждения, но, если не получится, то так и быть... [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux),   [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint),   [ссылка](http://linuxgid.ru/)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35106/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-max-zs).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в Вашем случае помогла бы программа telnet(telnetd). Она бы позволила присоединиться на конкретный адрес:порт другой машины и дальше уже просто отправили бы свое текстовое сообщение. Но, в данном случае, неизвестно, предустановлена ли она на Вашей плате (и можете ли Вы ее туда установить).